# Configuring PHP for pthreads

Tags: php, pthreads, centos

I am trying to install pthreads for PHP, [which is here](https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads).

In PHP manual of extention it says:

> To enable pthreads support, configure PHP with --enable-maintainer-zts
>   and --enable-pthreads.

I have a CentOS server which has PHP installed but I cant figure out how to reconfigure it with these settings on, I checked my `phpinfo()` can see current ./configure options.

I will happy if someone can show me how to reconfigure my php. Do I need to uninstall current PHP first then install another or is there any way to run this ./configure command easily. I have SSH access to my server.

Answer (score 2):

You could try install using PECL:

http://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads.

How to install PECL extensions:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

```
pecl install pthreads
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for help, it seems i already got pecl installed. but when i use pecl install pthreads command it says :
Failed to download pecl/pthreads within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.0.42, stability "beta", use "channel://pecl.php.net/pthreads-0.0.42" to install
install failed

Comment: and i need to use --enable-maintainer-zts as well

Answer (score 2):

I've written a tutorial about exactly this - [Compile PHP with pthreads and ZTS enabled](http://blog.flowl.info/2015/compile-php-5-6-pthreads-mongo-ubuntu/).

You must compile PHP as there are no prebuilt packages.

To reconfigure everything you'd use `./configure` mainly.

Answer (score 1):

if centos does not provide a thread safe version, you must compile php by own.

Answer (score 1):

You have to build pthreads for your centos op system. After that you can use it as extension...

Use the following tutorials

http://blog.slowbro.org/2013/08/compiling-php-55-with-pthreads-on-centos/

http://eddmann.com/posts/compiling-php-5-5-with-zts-and-pthreads-support/

Or simply read the manual...

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php